# Custom functions error: 'the expression cannot be used in a calculated column'

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access 2010 I am trying to use custom VBA functions in a calculated column. I get 'the expression cannot be used in a calculated column'.

Here are my steps:

1. Launch Access 2010.
2. Create a new database "DB".
3. Create a table "Table1" with a text column "Column1". Create a test row with "hello" in Column1.
4. On "Create" ribbon, click "Module" at the upper-right corner, which launches VBA editor.
5. In VBA editor "Project" window, there are two projects "ACWZTOOL" and "DB". Choose "DB" and select "Insert" -> "Module".
6. Write the following code:

   ```
   Public Function TestFunc() As String
       TestFunc = "test"
   End Function
   ```
7. "Debug" -> "Compile DB" passed, "Save" and closed VBA editor. Now "Module1" appears in "Modules" tab in the left pane.
8. In Table1, create a calculated column "Column2", with expression "Len([Column1])", the column works properly with the value in test row being 5.
9. Change the expression to "TestFunc()", the error pops up.
10. I tried a few other built-in functions, it seems only the "basic" ones are supported in expression builder. E.g. "InStrRev()" is also not recognized.

Comment: Note that having calculated fields in tables is poor practice. Calculated fields should really only be used in queries which can utilise user defined functions (providing they are in a standard module and not a class module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945943.aspx), user-defined functions are not allowed in calculated column expressions.  The relevant quote is in the "Read It" section:

> Be aware that calculated fields cannot call user-defined functions,
>   only built-in functions. In addition, you must supply all parameters
>   for methods that you call, even if the parameters are optional.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't come across that page during researching but even if I did I might not notice that section.