# MS ACCESS formatNumber in Calculated Field

Tags: ms-access, numbers, unique

I have a `uID` field linked to an auto number field `Num` that generates unique, custom numbering for each record in a table.

However the Expression used for the Data type keeps returning an error.

```
If Field1 = "Cat" then field (uID) must return "C" & [Num]. With the number format "000". ie C001, C010, C121 etc
IIf([Field1]="Cat","C" & formatNumber([Num],3) & [Num],"Unknown")
```

It seems Access doesn't recognise formatNumber used in this manner.

Comment: [num] returns always "000" or it gives a value in any 3 digit like '123' and you just need to add C123 that is what you need ??

Comment: I would like for a number 1, 10, 121 etc to return formatted index equivalent to C001, C010, C121.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your textbox control source

```
=IIf([Field1]="Cat";"C"+Format([NUM];"000");Null)
```

this will give you the output what you need.

Comment: I used =IIf([Field1]="Cat","C" & Format([NUM],"000"),Null) but I go error: The expression cannot be used in a calculated column. It seems Access does not recognise format().

Comment: where you are using this code? show me the screenshot if you can.

Comment: I think you are using this code directly on the datbase table column if that's the case than it will not work. it can be used in query but directly in to the database table it is not possible. check this out [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276587/custom-functions-error-the-expression-cannot-be-used-in-a-calculated-column